# Vertically center labels and inputs inside lists

Tags: css, html, forms

I have a form that I am going to put into a slider, I want to center the labels of each input field vertically within the li. Some of the labels will have two lines and some only one line. I will also want to center all of the radio buttons later on.

I have tried this so far but it does not work

```
    <li class="fill-in">
        <label for="sasqNumber">SASQ number (today's date i.e. dd_mm_yyyy):</label>
        <input type="text" name="sasqNumber" id="sasqNumber" value="" />
    </li>

#test ul li.fill-in label{
    text-align:right;
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    vertical-align:middle; 
    display:table-cell;
    margin:0 5% 0 0;
}
```

link to the site http://www.foresightaus.com.au/form/

Comment: This is a good reference on vertical alignment: [Understanding vertical-align, or "How (Not) To Vertically Center Content"](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html)

Comment: That is a good article but the examples seem to only work when there is a fixed height? My problem is that some of the labels have 2 lines of text rather than 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this very simple jquery script:

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.vAlign = function() {
    return this.each(function(i){
    var ah = $(this).height();
    var ph = $(this).parent().height();
    var mh = Math.ceil((ph-ah) / 2);
    $(this).css('margin-top', mh);
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Then call the function on any elements you want vertically aligned:

```
$('#example p').vAlign();
```

Comment: wow thanks that works perfectly. if you wouldn't mind can I ask what the (i) is doing in the function and what the math.ceil part is?

Comment: It stands for index, math.ceil basically rounds off any decimals to the nearest integer so you don't get any fractions of a pixel. Glad it worked! Much more reliable for this than css imo.

Answer (score -1):

Without editing your setup too much, I got it to look more centered. I added:

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
margin: -15px 5% 0 0
```

Comment: actually, it does not really work for the single lined labels :-/